# Deno import_map.json for supabase

Tags: intellij-idea, deno, supabase

I try to work with supabase edge functions in a Deno environment in IntelliJ Ultimate.
The corresponding plugin is already installed but inside my supabase folder the functions I wanna create do not support Deno IntelliSense which makes things quite hard.

Folder Structure:
[image]

I don't know why my IntelliSense breaks when working with Deno and/or how to retrieve the correct types from packages imported via import_map.json

import_map.json

```
{
  "imports": {
    "stripe": "https://esm.sh/stripe@11.12.0?target=deno",
    "std/server": "https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/http/server.ts"
  }
}
```

index.ts inside my 'get-ticket-information' function folder (The code is probably correct, but shows me errors because of missing types):

```
import { serve } from 'std/server'
import Stripe from 'stripe'

const stripe = new Stripe(Deno.env.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY') as string, {
  apiVersion: '2022-11-15',
  httpClient: Stripe.createFetchHttpClient(),
})
```

When trying to deploy to supabase via

```
 supabase functions deploy --no-verify-jwt get-ticket-information --debug
```

I do receive the following error too:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Relative import path "http" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ and not in import map from "https://esm.sh/v108/@types/node@16.18.12/http.d.ts"
      const ret = new Error(getStringFromWasm0(arg0, arg1));
```

Comment: did you try specifying a path to your `import.map.json` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Deno, Init command**? By default, the IDE expects it to be located in the project root. If it's located in a subfolder, the path to it has to be specified in init command

Comment: Yes, changed it to './supabase/functions/import_map.json'. Still won't work.

Comment: Typescript doesn't support import-map yet. In vscode, we need to  add  `paths` in tsconfig.json or jscofig.json.

Comment: From feb 22, we don't need to create separate file `import_map.json`. Add `imports` key in `deno.json`. Read more [issues/15816](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/15816)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the runtime error:

The Supabase CLI documentation for [`supabase functions deploy`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-functions-deploy) suggests that you must provide a path to the import map at the time of invocation:

> ### supabase functions deploy
>
> Deploy a Function to the linked Supabase project.
>
> *Basic usage:*
>
> ```txt
> supabase functions deploy <Function name> [flags]
> ```
>
> **Flags:**
>
> ```txt
> --import-map <string>
> ```
>
> Path to import map file.
>
> ...cont.

---

Regarding import maps as they relate to IDE integration and types:

This has already been covered on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74905332/438273), and is also covered in the manual in section 3.3: [Import Maps](https://deno.land/manual@v1.31.1/basics/import_maps).

Comment: Still the same error appears even when appending the import_map.json as flag :/

Comment: @MarkusG. I have the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Sadly not no :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the paths like following:

`import_map.json`

```
{
    "imports": {
      "std/http/server.ts": "https://deno.land/std@0.203.0/http/server.ts"
    }
}
```

You correspondending `index.ts`:

```
import { serve } from 'std/http/server.ts';
```

In the latest version(s) of deno, this package is deprecated, instead you should use `Deno.serve()` as a global function without any imports (if you plan to use the latest version of deno).